# Testing for a player with a certain score finds any player no matter what their score is

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have an objective called ninja, which can either have a score of 1 or 0. The command I am attempting to use is

```
/testfor @p[score_ninja=1]
```

However, the command returns "Found (my username)" rather than
"(My username) did not match the required data structure" when `ninja` has a value of 0 or 1, but not if it is higher than 1.

Am I using the command wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. Good first question, I have condensed it a bit and rolled your edit into the question. There is no need to signal edits like this (in fact it's strongly discouraged), since SE has a revision history that can be accessed by clicking on "edited X ago", which shows all the changes anyone made. Check out the [tour] and [help] if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is intended.

The [target selector argument](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments) `score_name=X` sets a maximum boundary for the score, rather than a specific value.

> **Selecting targets by score**
>
> `[score_name=SCORE]` — Selects only targets with a score in objective name of no more than SCORE.
>
> `[score_name_min=SCOREMIN]` — Selects only targets with a score in objective name of no less than SCOREMIN.
>
> For example, `@a[score_points_min=30,score_points=39]` will select all players with a score in objective "points" between 30 and 39 (inclusive).

To select only players/entities with a score of exactly `X` in the objective `name`, you have to both arguments at the same time, e.g.

```
/testfor @p[score_name_min=X,score_name=X]
```